# Dynamo DB Query and Scan Behavior Question

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I thought of this scenario in querying/scanning in DynamoDB table.

What if i want to get a single data in a table and i have 20k data in that table, and the data that im looking for is at 19k th row. Im using Scan with a limit 1000 for example. Does it consume throughput even though for the 19th time it does not returned any Item?. For Instance,

I have a User table:

```js
type UserTable{
   userId:ID!
   username:String,
   password:String
}
```

then my query

```js
var params = {
            TableName: "UserTable",
            FilterExpression: "username = :username",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":username": username
            },
            Limit: 1000
        };
```

How to effectively handle this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-query-scan.html)

> A Scan operation always scans the entire table or secondary index. It
>   then filters out values to provide the result you want, essentially
>   adding the extra step of removing data from the result set.

**Performance**

> If possible, you should avoid using a Scan operation on a large table
>   or index with a filter that removes many results. Also, as a table or
>   index grows, the Scan operation slows

**Read units**

> The Scan operation examines every item for the requested values and can
>   use up the provisioned throughput for a large table or index in a
>   single operation. For faster response times, design your tables and
>   indexes so that your applications can use Query instead of Scan

For better performance an less read unit consumption i advice you create [GSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general.html) using it with query

Answer (score 0):

A Scan operation will look at entire table and visits all records to find out which of them matches your filter criteria. So it will consume throughput enough to retrieve all the visited records. Scan operation is also very slow, especially if the table size is large.

To your second question, you can create a Secondary Index on the table with UserName as Hash key. Then you can convert the scan operation to a Query. That way it will only consume throughput enough for fetching one record.

[Read about Secondary Indices Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html)